# Adding JButton and rectangle to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, border-layout

Here's my simple code which draws rectangle on frame.How can I add button to this frame? I tried to set FlowLayout but then rectangle is not visible.Help please.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class test extends Canvas{
public static JFrame frame;
public static JButton button;

public void paint(Graphics graphics) {
    graphics.setColor(Color.yellow);
    graphics.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
    graphics.setColor(Color.red);
    graphics.drawRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
}

public static void main(String args[]){
    test x=new test();
    frame=new JFrame();
    button=new JButton();

    button.setSize(20,20);
    button.setText("Click");

    frame.setSize(500,500);
    frame.add(button);
    frame.add(x);
    frame.setVisible(true);     
}
}
```

Comment: What do you see? Which rectangle are you referring to?

Comment: Have you tried setting a preferredSize on the "test?"

Comment: Have you tried calling `super.paint(graphics)` in your `paint` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default layout for a `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` which can only accept one component per layout constraint.  The default when none is specified is `CENTER`.  So change:

```
frame.add(button);
frame.add(x);
```

To:

```
frame.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
frame.add(x);
```

And you should see both components.

Other tips:

1. Don't set the size of top level containers.  Instead layout the content & call `pack()`.
2. Don't mix Swing & AWT without good reason.  As the other poster mentioned, we'd typically use a `JPanel` for custom rendering in Swing.
3. The `BorderLayout` will ignore the size of the button and stretch it to fit.  To have it stay a certain size, set a preferred size and add it to a `FlowLayout`.  Add the `FlowLayout` to the `PAGE_START` constraint.

Comment: +1 for the suggestions. `"set a preferred size"` !!! Looks strange when you are the one suggesting this thingy...

Comment: @nIcEcOw I am.. not entirely convinced of the "don't ever set a preferred size" argument.  It seems to prevent using some components (e.g. `JTextPane` & `JEditorPane`) that have no default size, and crops up problems with others when put into a container (e.g. a `JComboBox` in a `JToolBar`).  Kleopatra would happily tell us to use a 3rd party layout, but I stick to JSE only, which don't typically allow setting sizes..  Let's put it this way.  I am very cautious to suggest it, but in cases like this of custom rendering in a component I would use it for that component.  ( But don't tell K.. ;)

Comment: LOL :-), sure, I won't. Yeah, true about those components, even with `JTable` to which I am attached now a days reading tutorials and all they using this method, every now and then even in Java Docs, so was a bit puzzled as to what to believe and what not to :-).

Answer (score 2):

Don't paint onto a `Canvas`. Paint onto a `JPanel`.

Have your class extend `JPanel`, and then override `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent()`!

Answer (score 0):

you must use Container, get Container of the frame then use layouts and add components to it using add() method.